# Laravel - How to get the inputs and pass it from one view to another view (Mpdf)

Tags: php, laravel, session, input, mpdf

I have a date range filter in my reporting view so when the user click download button it should pass the selected dates to pdf view.

The default date is the first day of current month until todays date and user can filter the date according to their needs.

How to pass those inputs to another view?

I should pass the $from and $to variable from both index and filter functions.

I have tried many ways but none of them works :(

Any suggestion?

Here's the codes :(

Controller

```
 public function index(Request $request){
 $startDate = Carbon::now();
        $from = $startDate->firstOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');
        $to = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

 return view('Reports.index',compact('from','to');
}

 public function filter(Request $request)
    {
        $from = Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_from'))->format('Y-m-d');
        $to = Carbon::parse($request->input('datepicker_to'))->format('Y-m-d');

  return view('Reports.index',compact('from','to');
}

public function print()
    {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('Reports.reportPDF');
        return $pdf->stream('my.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));
    }
```

Web

```
Route::get('print', 'reportController@print')->name('Reports.reportPDF');
```

Views

```
<a href="{{ route('Reports.reportPDF') }}" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-success" title="Download PDF" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></button></a>
```

Comment: you using `Barryvdh\DomPDF` ??

Comment: No i am using Meneses\LaravelMpdf\Facades\LaravelMpdf

Comment: pass filtering params to the print function or create a filtering function that used in both filter() and print()

Comment: @Kamran can u provide any example in Answer section

Comment: @Suvin94 something like [this](https://ideone.com/ovo0gy) and also pass to & from as URL query in your print link or anchor

Comment: @Kamran bro your code works but it doesn't get the input from the previous view instead it showing today's date for both from and to variable

Comment: Why don't you pass the two variable as parameters for the PDF function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieve this using **Session**. Thank you very much :)

Report.blade.php

```
@php(session(['to' =>  $to, date('Y-m-d')]))
@php(session(['from' =>  $from, date('Y-m-d')]))
```

PDF.blade.php

```
Showing Report From:
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse(request()->session()->get('from'))->formatLocalized('%d %b %Y') }}
To:
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse(request()->session()->get('to'))->formatLocalized('%d %b %Y') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the two variables in to PDF view.

```
public function print($from,$to)
    {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('Reports.reportPDF',['from'=>$from,'to'=>$to]);
        return $pdf->stream('my.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));
    }
```

Web

```
Route::get('print', 'reportController@print/{from}/{to}')->name('Reports.reportPDF');
```

Views

```
<a href="{{ route('Reports.reportPDF',[$from,$to]) }}" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-success" title="Download PDF" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-`download"></i></button></a>
```

Comment: Hey i am getting an error Method App\Http\Controllers\reportController::print/{from}/{to} does not exist

Comment: I have modified your code as well Route::get('/print2', 'reportController@print/{from}/{to}')->name('Reports.reportPDF,[$from,$to]');

Comment: Here's the link after clicked print button ''http://localhost/print2/%7B$from%7D/%7B$to%7D''

Comment: if you changed the method name to print2, you don't need to pass variables to route name. instead of name('Reports.reportPDF,[$from,$to]'); you can use, name('Reports.reportPDF2'). 
look like others are fine. but if you did everything in afine way your url should not be like that. It should pass correct values through the url.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that you are not doing it quite right.

There are some options:

- Make the action `print` accept parameters.
- Make the action `index` accept parameters and a parameter that flags
  for download (if the parameter comes, then your response would be a PDF download)
- Use the session as you did.

For me, the appropiate way would be make `print` action accept parameters.
Using the session is somewhat obscure and will be hard to maintain.

So to recap, this is what I recommend:

- Action `index` or `view` with date range filter.
- Action `download` with date range filter. (basically the same input
  as the `view` action). Of course, when clicking the button you would use JavaScript to collect the date range input currently being displayed to the user, then do an AJAX call to the `download` action.

This is the cleanest solution and avoids tightly coupling to the session, and is more readable and understandable.